# Angular materials autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to autocomplete my form using Angular materials. Here, I want to autocomplete the input form. For the suggestions to be displayed, I want to display the names of the stock names and symbols. I am getting the stock data from the following API:
http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=A

Whenever I type a new alphabet, the new text is taken and the new text is passed to the searchTextChange function in my code. The searchTextChange function makes ajax call to a PHP script which works at the back-end. The PHP script calls the API with the new text as the parameter and returns the JSON data returned by API. So, ultimately my searchTextChange function returns JSON data. I am able to log this JSON data to the console.

Now, the problem is, I am not able to display the data as suggestions. What changes do I need to make?

Here's my HTML + Angular code:

```
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <script language = "javascript">
          var finalData;
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('autoCompleteController', autoCompleteController);function autoCompleteController ($timeout, $q, $log) {
            var self = this; self.isDisabled    = false;
             self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
            self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
            function searchTextChange(text) {
               $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
                var str = text;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  finalData = this.responseText;
                console.log(finalData);
                return finalData;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Auto.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function selectedItemChange(item) {
               $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
            }  
         }  
      </script>
   </head>
    <body ng-app = "firstApplication" ng-cloak>
      <div ng-controller = "autoCompleteController as ctrl" layout = "column" ng-cloak>
         <md-content class = "md-padding">
            <form ng-submit = "$event.preventDefault()">
               <p><code>md-autocomplete</code> can be used to provide search results from
               local or remote data sources.</p><md-autocomplete
                  ng-disabled = "ctrl.isDisabled"
                  md-no-cache = "ctrl.noCache"
                  md-selected-item = "ctrl.selectedItem"
                  md-search-text-change = "ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                  md-search-text = "ctrl.searchText"
                  md-selected-item-change = "ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
                  md-items = "item in ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
                  md-item-text = "item.symbol"
                  md-min-length = "1"
                  placeholder = "eg.AAPL"> <md-item-template>
                     <span md-highlight-text = "ctrl.searchText"
                        md-highlight-flags = "^i">{{item.symbol}}</span>
                  </md-item-template> <md-not-found>
                     No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found. </md-not-found>
               </md-autocomplete>
               <br/>
            </form>
         </md-content>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*","Content-Type:application/json");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    // echo "Now process for " .$q;
    $APICall = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=".$q;

    $response = file_get_contents($APICall);
    echo $response;


}
else {
    echo "Not get method";
}
?>
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save the result in the scope:

```
   var finalData;
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('autoCompleteController', autoCompleteController);function autoCompleteController ($timeout, $q, $log,$scope) {
            var self = this; self.isDisabled    = false;
             self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
            self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;
            function searchTextChange(text) {
               $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
                var str = text;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  finalData = this.responseText;
                console.log(finalData);
                $scope.finalData =  finalData;
                //----^ here
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Auto.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function selectedItemChange(item) {
               $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
            }  
         }
```

change the loop to:

`md-items = "item in ctrl.finalData"`

you should better use $http like:

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in query(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.Symbol">
  <md-item-template>
     <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.Symbol + " - " + item.Name + " ("+ item.Exchange +")" }}</span>
  </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>

function autoCompleteController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.query = function(searchText) {
    return $http
      .get("Auto.php?q=" + searchText)
      .then(function(data) {
        return data.data;
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: There are no suggestions coming up. You can have a look at my page here:http://cs-server.usc.edu:25078/Trial3.html

Comment: did you added $scope to your controller `autoCompleteController ($timeout, $q, $log,$scope)` ?

Comment: I added the $scope to controller and there are no more errors. But there are no suggestions coming up. I am getting a loading... bar in place of my suggestions. Have a look at my implementation here: http://cs-server.usc.edu:25078/Trial3.html

Comment: ups, my bad, you have namespaced your controller, see updated answer

Comment: I made the changes with  md-items = "item in ctrl.finalData" and $scope.Any other changes to be made ? I  implemented the above mentioned change. Still not getting suggestions.

Comment: can't access the page :((

Comment: why do you have so many directives appended to the autocomplete?

Comment: okay, the output is exactly the same as shown in the image in the question. There are no suggestions. When I type a letter, it just says that " No States matching "input word" were found." .  There are no errors on the console. The console displays the JSON data, the data which we logged on console in our searchTextChange function.

Comment: try my second option using $http

Comment: should i remove other functions from autoCompleteController()

Comment: Still not getting suggestions. Just getting a loading... bar in place of the suggestions.

Comment: do `.then(function(data) {console.log(data)
        return data;
      });` and see if the data is coming back

Comment: Yes, I am getting some data on the console.

Comment: then the problem is in the autocomplete functionality

Comment: The console data looks like this: Array(10), status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}

Comment: What do I do to make my code work? Any other approach ?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. But there is one issue. The json data is in the form : {Symbol: "A", Name: "Agilent Technologies Inc", Exchange: "NYSE"} and so I am getting the whole of this in my suggestions. I want my suggestion to look like: A -  Agilent Technologies Inc (NYSE) . How do I format the data so that all the suggestions are shown in proper format ?

Comment: alter your template to your desired layout `<md-item-template>
                     <span md-highlight-text = "ctrl.searchText"
                        md-highlight-flags = "^i">{{item.Symbol}}</span>
                  </md-item-template>`

Comment: so I used : <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.Symbol + " - " + item.Name + " ("+ item.Exchange +")" }}</span>

Comment: @user45437 don't forget the green check :) glad to have helped

Comment: The suggestions are working perfectly, but when I select one of the suggestion, the input box shows: [object Object] . I want the Symbol to be shown whenever the suggestion is selected.

Comment: use the following directive `md-item-text="item.Symbol"`

Comment: Fantastic!! Worked. You are awesome!!

Comment: Is there any way to connect with you ?